# Manually padding a list of BatchEncodings using huggingface's tokenizer

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am having difficulties understanding the `tokenizer.pad` method from the huggingface transformers library. In order to optimize training, I am performing tokenization in the Dataset such that no complicated operations are performed during data loading. My dataset looks like:

```py
class DatasetTokenized(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame, text_column: str,
                 label_columns: List[str], tokenizer_name: str):
        super(DatasetTokenized, self).__init__()

        self.data = data
        self.text_column = text_column
        self.label_columns = label_columns
        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_name)
        self.tokenized_data = self.tokenize_data(data)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.tokenized_data)

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Dict:
        return self.tokenized_data[index]

    def tokenize_data(self, data: pd.DataFrame):
        tokenized_data = []

        print('Tokenizing data:')
        for _, row in tqdm(data.iterrows(), total=len(data)):

            text = row[self.text_column]
            labels = row[self.label_columns]
            encoding = self.tokenizer(text,
                                      add_special_tokens=True,
                                      max_length=512,
                                      padding=False,
                                      truncation=True,
                                      return_attention_mask=True,
                                      return_tensors='pt')

            tokenized_data.append({
                'text': text,
                'encoding': encoding,
                'labels': torch.FloatTensor(labels)
            })

        return tokenized_data
```

and my collator looks like:

```py
class BertCollatorTokenized:

    def __init__(self, tokenizer_name: str):
        super(BertCollatorTokenized, self).__init__()

        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_name)

    def __call__(self, batch: List[Any]):
        text, encodings, labels = zip(
            *[[sample['text'], sample['encoding'], sample['labels']]
              for sample in batch])

        encodings = list(encodings)
        encodings = self.tokenizer.pad(encodings,
                                       max_length=512,
                                       padding='longest',
                                       return_tensors='pt')

        return {
            'text': text,
            'input_ids': encodings['input_ids'],
            'attention_mask': encodings['attention_mask'],
            'labels': torch.FloatTensor(labels)
        }
```

I have confirmed that `encodings` is a list of `BatchEncoding` as required by `tokenizer.pad`. However, I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length.

Which is a bit confusing as that should be the whole point of using `tokenizer.pad`. Anyone has an idea of what's going on?

Comment: The codebase of HuggingFace is a mess, what's wrong with using native torch ops to pad? If you want to stick with the HF implementation, could it be the case that you need `encode` rather than `tokenize` in `DatasetTokenized.tokenize_data`?

Comment: I am using the `__call__` method of the tokenizer which in the background will call `encode` or `batch_encode` automatically. There is nothing wrong with using native torch functions, but I wanted to figure out a way how to do this with the HF API.

Comment: You're right, I misread (apologies).